# Notification banners not showing for apps being debugged?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to make notification banners show for an app that is being debugged on Xcode?

Not working for me. When I stop the app on Xcode, notification banners show. If the app is being debugged, notification banners won't show.

When I send a notification, **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:** is triggered and the notification is received on the userInfo of this method, but the notification banner never appears.

Yes, my device is configured to show notifications as banners for this app. I have double verified that.

Any thoughts?

thanks.

Comment: ahhh, do you mean that the banner never shows for apps that are opened? Now it makes sense. Please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banners will appear only when the app is closed/in the background. Otherwise, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called.